# Libreoffice doesnt work since update to ubuntu 15.04

Tags: libreoffice

The update to Ubuntu 15.04 causes following problem. When I try to open LibreOffice the screen goes black and then shows following message for a few seconds:

```
starting version 219
[   OK    ] Started Light Display Manager.
            Starting WPA supplicant...
                                      [   OK   ] Started WPA supplicant.
```

Then the screen turns black again and Ubuntu restarts. All other programs work as usual. Any idea what causes this and how I can solve it?

Comment: please run it from terminal and give us console output

Comment: I think, his x server crashes... So we need information about your hardware, and which proprietary drivers you have installed.

Comment: @user3417815 well if it crashes again, you will never get the terminal output. you need to redirect to a file, hoping it will get flushed to disk before the reboot: `libreoffice 2>&1 >libreoffice_crash_log.txt`

Comment: @solstice Terminal output will be received anyway. If terminal app crashed or not, of course I don't suggest to just stare at screen and try to catch anything before screen goes black :) Don't know op skills unfortunatelly, maybe he already know about file redirection. I suggest to run it through debugger also, it can give usefull output as well

Comment: OP says that ubuntu is crashing not only libreoffice

Comment: "the screen turns black and then shows following message for some seconds" it's not immediate crash of system. OP didn't said so.

Comment: what's the version of libreoffice suite installed on system?

Comment: Have you tried other programs yet(such as Firefox, etc.)? It's possible that, if no other program has this issue, it could be directly related to a OpenOffice issue.

Comment: i`ve tried all other programmes i`m using (firefix, gimp, scribus, videos...), everything works as before the update.

my computer is a lenovo z50 netbook. the prozessor is AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G × 4 and the graphic card is Gallium 0.4 on AMD KAVERI
any more hardware information needed?

what are "propietary" drivers? where do i find information about them?
how do i start a programme via terminal?
i need step-by-step assistance, please, coz i`m no big expert about all this. sorry.

Comment: @blimey in order to provide your system information it's suggested to get inxi. Open up a terminal and copy paste this: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unit193/inxi && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install inxi && inxi -F`

Comment: This is clearly an X server crash, probably caused by a video driver bug.  `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` should have additional information.

Comment: I second that @MariusGedminas. Today I tested with a Fedora LiveUSB and the same happened. It showed, that acpi_radeon (and smth else, didn't catch it) is causing the issue with the response "cannot detect backlight", or similar. I assume a workaround would be to try and play with boot parameters, **nomodeset** perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to solve this is to update the source from which the Libreoffice update is triggered. To automatically get the latest stable Libreoffice, you may need to add the following repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa 
sudo apt-get update sudo
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Cheers,