# LibreOffice crashes on startup after upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity, kde, libreoffice, crash

I would have up-voted or responded to this thread but I do not have enough rep: [Libreoffice doesnt work since update to ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617829/libreoffice-doesnt-work-since-update-to-ubuntu-15-04)

After an upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 LibreOffice (Writer, Calc etc) crashes on startup. It also logs me out and restarts X server.

I tried running
     `gksu libreoffice 2>&1 >libreoffice_crash_log.txt`
but the log contains 0 bytes. I also tried renaming `/home/me/.config/libreoffice` to `/home/me/.config/libreoffice.old` to no avail. This has been happening since my upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04. I have the same symptoms on the KDE (plasma) desktop as well as Unity. My video card is a Radeon HD 7990 and I'm using the wrapper driver from X.Org. The log `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` contains no tell-tale crash entries.

What else can I verify to help solve this  issue?

Edit - added logfile `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`

```
[   263.625] reporting 12 5 28 228
[   334.104] (EE) 
[   334.104] (EE) Backtrace:
[   334.121] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x7f9e170bb556]
[   334.121] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9e16f08000+0x1b7749) [0x7f9e170bf749]
[   334.122] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f9e14b90000+0x352f0) [0x7f9e14bc52f0]
[   334.122] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbBltOne+0x447) [0x7f9e0aeb1b57]
[   334.122] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbCopy1toN+0x267) [0x7f9e0aeb2687]
[   334.122] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f9e103b8000+0xa410) [0x7f9e103c2410]
[   334.122] (EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (miCopyRegion+0x1a7) [0x7f9e1709baf7]
[   334.122] (EE) 7: /usr/bin/X (miDoCopy+0x44e) [0x7f9e1709c08e]
[   334.122] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f9e103b8000+0xb860) [0x7f9e103c3860]
[   334.122] (EE) 9: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9e16f08000+0x13eb01) [0x7f9e17046b01]
[   334.122] (EE) 10: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9e16f08000+0x542a7) [0x7f9e16f5c2a7]
[   334.122] (EE) 11: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9e16f08000+0x580a7) [0x7f9e16f600a7]
[   334.122] (EE) 12: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9e16f08000+0x5c29b) [0x7f9e16f6429b]
[   334.122] (EE) 13: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f9e14bb0a40]
[   334.122] (EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9e16f08000+0x4662e) [0x7f9e16f4e62e]
[   334.122] (EE) 
[   334.122] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[   334.122] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   334.122] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[   334.122] (EE) 
[   334.123] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   334.123] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   334.123] (EE) 
[   334.123] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[   334.133] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: I don't have exact this problem, but today LibreOffice crashed with really no good reason. I clicked on toolbar to customize it... and it crashed :-( I experienced two-three different similar situation... I am thinking to return to 14.10 or 14.04.

Comment: Happens also in Ubuntu GNOME 15.04, startup crash, restarts X-server, can't report anything.

Comment: This is a serious bug in the X server (most likely in the video driver).  Check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`, it should have some information.  (The .log without .old starts fresh when X crashes and is re-started to show the login screen.)

Comment: BTW using 'gksu' to run libreoffice is a bad idea and shouldn't be necessary.  (But it can't be the reason for the crash.)

Comment: I only used 'gksu' to try and eliminate the profile as the bug source.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622864/ubuntu-crashes-when-i-open-libreoffice) solved my problem. To summarize, just install `fglrx-updates`.