# Ubuntu crashes when I open LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, 15.04, crash

Whenever I try to open LibreOffice, Ubuntu stops running and opens the text-y DOS looking screen and restarts light display manager. Every time I open any of the LibreOffice office programs it crashes. I have no idea what is happening, I am a bit new to Ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: Have you added a PPA for LibreOffice?

Comment: How do I do that? and isn't there already one by default in Ubuntu? Since it comes with LibreOffice?

Comment: I wanted to know if you've done it. OK, obviously not.

Comment: I added a PPA, it still crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have the same problem.
Just use **fglrx-updates** as video controller, radeon has a bug.
That was the solution for me.
I think there is a problem with Ubuntu 15.04 and ATI cards

Comment: It's not only Ubuntu that has the same bug. Fedora does too. It's driver related, but in my case using fglrx didn't help, it in fact made my system unbootable.